# Web Parts sharing images/javascript files etc

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm developing a few web parts and I have a Sharepoint site with 2 sub-sites:

hxxp://sharepointserver/sites/portal1

hxxp://sharepointserver/sites/portal2

(hxxp to get around the spam filter)

In the local file system, the site is created in:

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\8080\

There are a few images, a couple of javascript files and a css file that get installed in (stsadm -globalinstall):

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\8080\wpresources\mywebparts\

Now the problem is when I use the ClassResourcePath property from a web part, depending on what site the web part has been added to, the url is (for example):

hxxp://sharepointserver/sites/portal[1|2]/wpresources/mywebparts/mywebparts.css

This fails as the file url should be:

hxxp://sharepointserver/wpresources/mywebparts/mywebparts.css

It feels like I am using the ClassResourcePath incorrectly, but I'm not sure what other options there are to share common files between web parts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some options:

1. You can put the common files in the _layouts directory. If you are using MOSS 2007 you can use solution deployment to automate this.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163379.aspx
2. You can embed your resources in the assembly itself. And then access it:
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: Thanks for getting back. We still have to support Sharepoint 2003. So we deploy a cab with dwp files. Using stsadm -o addwppack -globalinstall etc. I found this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583149(office.11).aspx#sharepoint_deployingwebparts_topic8 which says that if you install to the gac, the ClassResource files will go in the local_drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\wpresources. That seems to be right, but install doesn't seem to put it in that directory. Any ideas?

Comment: stsadm -o addwppack -globalinstall -filename mywebparts.cab